# Lebesgue integral in Reed and Simon

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f \ge 0$ be a function and let $\mu$ be the Lesbegue measure. Define $\sum_n(f)$ as
\begin{equation}
\sum_n(f):= \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{m}{n}\mu\left(f^{-1}\left[\left[\frac{m}{n},\frac{m+1}{n}\right)\right]\right),
\end{equation} with $n \in \mathbb{N}\backslash\{0\}$. Prove that $\sum_{2n}(f) \ge \sum_n(f)$.

MY ATTEMPT

We first notice that
\begin{equation}
\frac{m+1}{n}\ge \frac{m}{n} \ge \frac{m+1}{2n} \ge \frac{m}{2n}
\end{equation}
if $m \neq 0$.

We can write
\begin{equation}
\sum_{2n}(f) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{m}{2n}\mu\left(f^{-1}\left[\left[\frac{m}{2n},\frac{m+1}{2n}\right)\right]\right)
\end{equation}

From here on I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried? On this forum it is expected of askers to include their efforts and/or research. Think of it as putting in as much time and effort in your question as you would like the volunteers here to put in to answer it. In addition, this will let us help you with more adequate comments and answers, and this will let both you and us see exactly what went wrong in what you've tried, or what you misunderstood or didn't understand. As an aside, link-only questions or answers are frowned upon here, you should include the relevant information in the body of your question.

Comment: You'll note that what's written for the part you're worried about is actually $\sum_{2n}$ with $2n$ and not $2^n$. The authors could have made it clearer by choosing a different letter, for example $2k$ and $2^n$, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $m,n$ fixed, let $a:=\mu\left(f^{-1}\left[\left[\frac{2m}{2n},\frac{2m+1}{2n}\right)\right]\right)$ and $b:=\mu\left(f^{-1}\left[\left[\frac{2m+1}{2n},\frac{2m+2}{2n}\right)\right]\right).$
$$\frac{2m}{2n}a+\frac{2m+1}{2n}b\ge\frac mn(a+b).$$